# Does anyone know how to deform this geometry to this surface?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I'm trying these objects, shrinkwrap to this plane on the left but unfortunately my every try ends up with nothing happening or deforming the object.
I don't know what to do?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have some reference of final result? Probably Surface Deform modifier?

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=m5OOQ8RB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/m5OOQ8RB/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the vertex group that is selected in the *Lattice* modifier of the object *Cube*:

[image]

Also don't forget to recalculate the normals of *Body_Guidemesh.001*

Comment: ??? just remove Group? ... Lattice object - Shrinkwrap > Projection > On Surface (Negative)

Comment: The vertex group of the object called Cube

Comment: @vklidu could you please elaborate? Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry ... Just removing vertex group does nothing for me. I had to change Shrinkwrap method to Projection type (etc. mentioned in my first comment) to get Lattice object shrink.

Comment: The default option works for me, it may not be the best option, Project may be preferable as you say, but in both cases the problem is that the object called Cube doesn't deform, which seems to be his problem?